# Selecting elements including nested children

Tags: javascript

I have a few rows with linked elements in them. The code looks like this:

```
<a href="link" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-lat="30.25552298" data-lon="-97.555554">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-8 col-xl-9 lead">
            label
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <span class="badge bg-success"><small>33</small></span> 
          <strong>5 mi.</strong>
       </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

Then I use event listeners to call couple functions when my mouse moves over the links:

```
let loc = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-lat]");
                            
var marker;

loc.forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener("mouseover", locOver);
    node.addEventListener("mouseout", locOut);
})
                            
function locOver(event) {
   var llt = event.target.dataset["lat"],
       lln = event.target.dataset["lon"];
                                    
   marker = L.marker([llt, lln]).addTo(map);
}
                      
function locOut(event) {
   marker.remove();
}
```

Since there's a little padding on the link it works great when a mouse enters it, however, as soon as the mouse hits divs within the link the marker disappears, which seems weird to me since it's still linked.

I've tried modifying selector like this:

```
let loc = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-lat] div");
```

But my code just stops working, and no marker is shown. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, not `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Comment: Wow, I missed that entirely. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it as the proper one. Thanks.